# Excel Reference A2= 4 there fore B6=-4

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to to write an equation in column B that looks at Column A finds the first non zero value above that row and returns that value as negative.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "above that row".

Answer (score 0):

in **B6** enter:

```
=-INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,A:A<>0,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does "above that row" mean the row above the row of the cell entered formula in?

Based on you example, if you need to find the first non zero value above that row 6, please try following array formula, then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

`=IFNA(-INDEX(A:A,MATCH(,0/(A$1:INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1)<>0),)),"No")`

[image]

[image]

Comment: So to Continue this topic if i am in row 6 I need to find the first Row above that has a value and return the negative. So check 5,4,3,2,1 and stop once a value also another to answer way to get a solution is IF  A2=4 then i  need to go over 1 column and down 4 and make that -4  if A7=2 then B9= -2. It is almost an offset number but the offset is different based on the value in that cell.

Comment: @Matthew emm, I think I am a little confused, if there is a value 4 in A2 and a value 2 in A7 , values in other cells of column are 0, would B9 be -4?